# TListView.BeginUpdate prevents hints from showing on UNRELATED controls

Tags: delphi, vcl, hint, delphi-11-alexandria, tlistview

When hovering the mouse over a control that has a hint, that hint is shown (`ShowHint` is True).

For some reason, TListView.BeginUpdate prevents the hint from being shown, even though the control has nothing to do with the listview.

Reproduction:

```
var
  DoOnce: Boolean = False;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  procedure Setup;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    // problem occurs even when NOT created by code
    // this is just to make reproduction easier
    for I := 1 to 3 do
      with TButton.Create(Form1) do begin
        Parent := Form1;
        Hint := IntToStr(I);
        ShowHint := True;
        Top := 8;
        Left := 8 + I * (Width + 8);
      end;
    ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  end;

begin
  if not DoOnce then begin
    DoOnce := True;
    Setup;
  end;
  with Timer1 do begin
    Interval := 250;
    Enabled := not Enabled;
    Form1.Caption := BoolToStr(Enabled, True);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Form1.ListView1.Items do begin
    BeginUpdate;
    Sleep(1);
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

When the timer is enabled, hovering the mouse over the buttons will not show their hints (exception: if a button has shown its hint -- when the timer was disabled -- the hint will still be shown; this however applies only to the LAST button to show its hint)

Since the timer's code does not access the buttons in any way, I do not understand this behavior. Can anyone explain what is happening and how to fix this?

(In case this helps: this is a MRE, in actual code the listview is updated via Queue from a thread at 250ms intervals)

EDIT:
this is cause by `SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);` in TListItems.SetUpdateState.
but why does a listview code affect other unrelated controls...

Comment: I don't really understand what you are describing. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify the issue better?

Comment: Remy Lebeau: it's difficult to describe a weird issue that i don't understand, but i've done my best to clarify. hopefully the reproduction at least is now a bit clearer.